# Reducing code view of a source page

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Is there any shortcut reducing the code view of all a source code page?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(CTRL + M, CTRL + L) - Sets all regions to the same collapsed or expanded state.